# OSB 12C REST client to EJB backend calling

Tags: soa, osb, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-soa

I have just started working in OSB-12c.

I need to use OSB when a client using REST protocol needs to connect with Backend that uses EJB.

I need help in converter part. Do I need to write java code for REST to EJB conversion or this can be handled in OSB as well. If yes, then please tell me how. Or this conversion can also be done via converter classes using converter interface in OSB (I read this OSB cook book).

Can anyone please help how to do this REST to EJB conversion in OSB 12c.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more info than that. Which bit are you actually having problems with?

Comment: I need help in converter part. Do I need to write java code for REST to EJB conversion or this can be handled in OSB as well. If yes, then please tell me how. Or this conversion can also be done via converter classes using converter interface in OSB (I read this OSB cook book).

Comment: Thanks! I did some examples on OSB 12.1.2 and used EJB adapters. There is still some issues in EJB adapters in OSB 12.1.2 which I will start discussing in a separate thread.